# Minimal project that simply gathers request form values and stores to db, what java framework?

Tags: java

I simply want to expose a URL in a web application, and then I will post information to that url and take the form data and save it do a database.

That's basically all I need to do.

I'm newish to java frameworks, what do I need for a project like this?  I don't really need the spring framework which I am "familiar" with.

Can someone direct me to what I need to setup a project library wise etc.

BTW, does java have any tools for pushing code to tomcat?  Something like how the ruby world uses capistrano?

Comment: If you're already familiar with it, why *not* just use Spring? Minimal configuration, trivial JDBC impl... is there a specific reason to avoid it?

Comment: @DaveNewton Well I have to build this to handle 2-3K requests per second, so I don't want the overhead.

Comment: Hmm, not too much overhead, but ok. I'm with Jack, then, just use servlets and JDBC.

Comment: well it did take me a few weeks just to get all the dependancies setup with spring/nhibernate/log4net/ and whatever else I used sigh :)

Comment: That's why there's Maven :) You can deploy using an Ant task, but it's generally just dropping a war file into a directory.

Answer (score 2):

If it really is as minimal as you say it is, you don't really need a framework--just use the plain old Servlet API that comes with Java EE and JDBC.

As for pushing code to Tomcat, all you need to do is get the `.war` file into the `webapps` directory.  You could probably write a basic shell script to do something like

```
cp myapp.war $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/myapp.war
```

Comment: oh I see, so as long as I have the java sdk, i'm set?

Comment: @codecompleting Basically, yes.  If you can write a web application using Spring, you can write one using the Servlet API.  Eclipse (the Java EE version) and NetBeans both have built-in wizards for setting up a web application.

Comment: don't use the wizards you end up with code that is unmanagable outside eclipse, what it generates sucks, learn to use Maven or at least Ant.

Answer (score 2):

This minimal project will need a minimal servlet to be deployed into a servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty, etc).

There is a lot written about to start with servlets. Maybe start with this one:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/index.html .

For database access you may start with the java.sql package: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html